# Update query with multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have recently created a tournament bracket in which this is the SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE `".TABLE_PREFIX."tnybracket` ( 
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
  `gid` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `tid` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `round` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `player1` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
  `player1uid` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
  `player1gt` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
  `player2` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
  `player2uid` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
  `player2gt` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
  `winner` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
  `winneruid` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
  `winnergt` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have it set up to where there is 8 of these with positions going from 1 through 8. As you can see here, http://i.gyazo.com/d106e9bac3f4a24f5253a36c498bbedf.png, there is 8 empty rows with the correct position numbers. Now I am trying to do an update query which tries to register a member to the bracket. However, before just updating a username, there are a couple things that need to be determined. If all player1 and player2 rows are empty for every single one, then update the "username" into player1 according to the position. (So, if all are empty, it would go in position 1 because of the order). However, if everything is empty except for player 1 in position 1, then it needs to update player 2 in position 1. Then after that it will keep going until all 8 positions are filled in order.
So when a user signs up, I have tried to run this code:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE MyBB_tnybracket
        SET player1="$username"
        WHERE round=1';
```

However, this obviously isn't right. I need to check player 1 and player 2 for being empty, then determine which one to go into. This is as far as I have gotten before I have come completely stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: 
Since this is rather confusing, I'll go into a bit more detail. Here is the table: 
http://i.gyazo.com/d106e9bac3f4a24f5253a36c498bbedf.png
And here is how it looks on my website
http://i.gyazo.com/19197e2bda98d8ae4cb3438272f6f10b.png

I have already inserted all the rows necessary for tournament, they are just blank. Now, when members sign up for the tournament, I need their username inserted in either Player 1 or Player 2. For example, if the tournament has all blank rows with no information (like in the table), then the username of the guy who signed up will go in Player 1. But if another person registers (and no on else, just 2 people), then his information will have to go into Player 2 on the same row. However, if a 3rd person registers, he will have to go into a new row as Player 1 again. And the cycle basically starts over, 4th person goes under Player on the new row.

Comment: can you please create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for your data and please [upload the image](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/218121) to stackoverflow

Comment: use a procedure, it will solve your problem

Comment: I tried to add more information to help you guys determine my problem.

Answer (score 0):

IIWM I'd break it into two tables:

games:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
`name` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
`gid` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`tid` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`round` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`position` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

players:

```
`player` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
`playeruid` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
`playergt` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
```

Then add players to the 'players' list as they sign up. Your php would do a join between the two to make up games for the brackets. Every time you get two signed up for a game you start a new one.

This way you won't be limited to just the 8 slots in your initial schema.